# Feasibility of an interactive movie app

Tags: performance, facebook-apps, reliability

I'm researching different platforms for an interactive movie app I'm going to be developing and I'd like to know if this is possible and *feasible*, in that users would actually get acceptable performance, reliability and so on.

The movies are going to be well under 30 minutes, live-action and won't need to be very high def, but will require a framerate suitable for live-action. I'm intending on porting(?) this to various mobile apps. (although I've yet to learn what the difference is between an fb app and an fb app for the various mobile devices)

In case it needs said, I'm an experienced developer, but I've not done any fb apps.

Comment: What is your question? You dont need to introduce yourself, this site is for asking/answering questions.

Comment: I put it in a Jeopardy sort of way, but I'm asking if it is possible and feasible to make an fb app that is basically an interactive movie

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the most suitable place to ask this but anyway...

Have a look at [This Exquisite Forest](http://www.exquisiteforest.com/), it might provide some tips. I think HTML5 is quite promising for such project.

Comment: It's the most suitable place available. I wanted to post this on the app developer's group on fb, but the place seems dead.

What's the Exquisite Forest? It doesn't work for me.